# What are headers added to Twitter v1.1 get user timeline feed

Tags: android, twitter

I added the following fields

```
 HttpClient cli = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(twit_baseurl);
 httpget.addHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeaderValue);
```

it shows error as,

```
 {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
```

Help me to solve this,thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Arun you can use https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/ to achieve ur objective

Answer (score 0):

Download the jar file from below given link and use, it is updated with Twitter API v1.1, to know how to use the jar file browse source=>Trunk=>MainActivity.java:

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-and-twitter-posting/